# why my localhost slower than internet?

Tags: localhost, zend-server-ce

I newly installed Zend Server CE in windows xp. I installed it in D:\Zend instead of default directory.Other than that, everything goes with default settings.
My localhost is slower than internet.
Should I re-install it to default installation directory to allow normal speed? or is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Well, it's on XP and that's not an ideal OS for almost anything.  How's your other site that your running on locally?

Comment: I don't have other sites. Only a Wordpress site. However, the Zend Server control page and index page is loaded very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location shouldn't affect.

Are you using Apache to run Zend? [This ServerFault solution could be the cause for you](https://serverfault.com/questions/66347/localhost-response-very-slow-why):

> There are two ways to set up PHP to work with Apache 2.0.x on Windows. One is to use the CGI binary the other is to use the Apache module DLL. In either case you need to edit your httpd.conf to configure Apache to work with PHP and then restart the server. [PHP DOCS]
>
> And so I went into the Apache's settings and saw where the problem
>   was. I had it set-up as CGI, instead of loading it as a module. This
>   caused the php-cgi.exe start up and shut down everytime I made a
>   request. This was slowing my localhost-development down.
>
> Changed the settings to load PHP as Apache MODULE and now it all works
>   perfectly :) Thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks! lots of solutions in that post, I should figure out one from there.